# Basic Clique Complexity Question

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics, big-o-notation, clique

A question in a textbook says, suppose the regular Clique problem, which takes as input a graph G and a natural number k, and returns whether or not G has a clique of size >= k, can be decided in time T(n) (for some function T: N → N) where n is the size of the input. Then, prove that the problem of finding the size of the largest clique in G can be decided in time O(nT(n)).

Intuitively, I understand you just have to call the algorithm deciding the Clique problem on k = n, n-1, etc until you get the size of the largest clique. However, I realised I am unsure why this takes time O(nT(n)). Does n in this case represent the size of the input, right? But I realised that the two problems take different inputs (the regular Clique takes <G,k> and this problem takes just ), so when I call the algorithm for regular clique on <G,size of V>, <G, size of V-1>, etc, how do I know the size of those inputs? Also, can I assume G is given as an adjacency list? Any help would be much appreciated, and I can clarify anything if need be.

Comment: Presumably $n$ is the number of vertices.

Comment: Actually I mean the size of the input